# How to play/stream/cast sound and video separately to different devices

Tags: bluetooth-audio, video-streaming, dlna, miracast

**What I have.**

- Portable Projector with DLNA & Miracast functionality.
- 5.1 Channel speaker with bluetooth.
- Android devices version Marshmallow[6.0](Alternate devices with Lollipop[5.1] also available)

**Current situation.**

- Movie(Video & Audio) streamed to projector from android device via DLNA/Miracast
- Stereo Output from projector to the 5.1 Channel Speakers.

**Problem.**

- 5.1 Channel Speakers becomes just stereo speakers.
- Speaker placements dependent on placement of projector.(I want to fix
  them and not not    move them).

**What I am looking for.**

- Stream **ONLY** the video playback to the projector from the android device
  via DLNA/Miracast.
- Stream **ONLY** the audio playback from android device to 5.1 channel speakers via bluetooth.

*Can this be done? is there any app available for the same?*

Answer (score 0):

Possible with android 5. Using zenfone 2 videocast to WiDi and audio to JBL Charge 3. 
It is not possible with android 6

Comment: can you list out the steps how you did it.